# Origin of "Interficere"?

Tags: etymology

I don't understand the etymology of interfacio: inter + facio.

How it became "to kill"? What is the link between "to do between"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex verbs like tr. *interficere* 'to kill' and intr. *interire* 'to die' contain the prefix *inter-*, which some scholars (e.g., [López Moreda (1987: page 222)](http://62.204.194.45/fez/eserv/bibliuned:Epos-CAAD79C7-C9D4-7192-F631-75E2A95FDB77/Documento.pdf), among others) have claimed is related to the suffix **-tero*, which can express ["a **separative** function"](https://books.google.es/books?id=Gxq540du26oC&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=suffix%20*tero%20benveniste%20separative&source=bl&ots=eZ6hGC_WOp&sig=ACfU3U1Z1AJWUdE4ztIwkpsAm--FS5jA6w&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD9eC27crlAhULlhQKHVarBa0Q6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=suffix%20*tero%20benveniste%20separative&f=false) (cf. Benveniste (1948)). According to López Moreda, i.a., the original meaning of *interficere* is 'to put in between by separating' [cf. also the previous relevant source pointed out below by AlexB on Hermann Hirt (1928) *Indogermanische Grammatik* (volume IV, page 59)].

[Filimonov (2019: page 86)](http://philclass.spbu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Filimonov-E.G.-Dual-Semantics-of-the-Latin-inter-.pdf), among others, also points out a parallelism with Sanskrit *antar-dha* ‘to kill, destroy’ (lit. ‘in the middle, between’-‘put’). In this respect see also the article by Sandoz, Cl (1976). “Du latin *interficio* au védique *antar dha*”. *Bulletin de la Société de Linguistique* LXXI: 207-219 [but see TKR's remark below on the alleged parallelism given by Filimonov (2019: 86)]. A further parallelism between Lat. *inter* and Hittite [*istarna*](https://books.google.es/books?id=LbG8vw_pva8C&pg=PA482&lpg=PA482&dq=separation%20separately%20interficere%20inter&source=bl&ots=_UHjLmSawI&sig=ACfU3U1u4yUHEt9Pxq5SaIGiQF05mR3yKg&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7_I326crlAhWTDWMBHUh1CL8Q6AEwBHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=separation%20separately%20interficere%20inter&f=false) can also be pointed out to give evidence for the separative component.

Assuming, along with López Moreda et al., that the original meaning of the causative change of state verb *interficere*  is 'to put in between by separating', it is also relevant to point out that the separation idea involved in this verb is clearly related to its privative use in Early Latin: e.g., *Salue, qui me interfecisti paene uita et lumine* (Pl. *Truc.* 518). Hence its meaning 'to cause me to be separated from life'. Cf. also the same definition provided by the Indo-Europeanist [Meier-Brügger (2003: page 187)](https://caio.ueberalles.net/Indo-European-Linguistics-Introduction/Indo-European_Linguistics%20-%20Michael%20Meier-Bru%CC%88gger.pdf):  "*interficere*: 'to separate (from life), to make disappear'.

Finally, as for the causation idea, it is obvious that it is involved in *interficere*, since the transitive verb *facere* means 'to do/to cause' (cf. the intransitive-unaccusative verb *interire*, which does not express 'causation' but only 'change (of state)').

Comment: I don't understand this etymology -- *inter* means "between", and has no specific idea of separation (even if it ultimately contains a suffix which can express separation, which I'm not sure about either). Also for Skt *antar-dhā* I'm not finding a sense "kill, destroy" in Monier Williams (the standard Skt-Eng dictionary).

Comment: @TKR  In the paper linked above López Moreda (1987: 222) says that the verb _interficere_ "acquires the separative pejorative meaning of the sufix *-tero" (Sp. "adquiere el significado peyorativo separativo del sufijo _*-tero_"), without giving more details and only referring in a footnote to the works by Benveniste (1949), Sandoz (1976), and his own doctoral dissertation on compounds of _facio_ (López Moreda (1985)).

Comment: @TKR. As for its comparison with Sanskrit, Filimonov (2019: 86; paper linked below) points out the following parallelism: Skr. _antar-gam_ (lit. ‘in the middle, between’-‘go’) ‘disappear’ (Apte 1957, 124) — _antar-dha_ ‘to kill, destroy’ (lit. ‘in the middle, between’-‘put’) (Mayrhofer 1992, 76) =_ inter-ficere_ (source: http://philclass.spbu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Filimonov-E.G.-Dual-Semantics-of-the-Latin-inter-.pdf ).

Comment: Thanks, the Filimonov paper is a little clearer (but only a little...). So if I understand correctly, the semantic link with "separation" is that to place something "between" two things is to separate those things; hence *interficere* comes to mean "separate", and then specializes to "separate from life, kill", I suppose by euphemism?

Comment: (Btw Mayrhofer 1992:76 doesn't give any definition for *antar-dhā*, which as far as I can tell means "place within, conceal" rather than "kill".)

Comment: I've just found this interesting/intriguing parallelism with a form in Hittite _istarna_. See page 482: "(...) its specific usages, like those of Lat. _inter_, spring from suffix _*ter_ which singles out the marked member of a binary pair ('**separately** within'). Source: https://books.google.es/books?id=LbG8vw_pva8C&pg=PA482&lpg=PA482&dq=separative+interficere+inter&source=bl&ots=_UHjLlU9tC&sig=ACfU3U25HTYiSwBb9Xh50DrZ4pYjKTJMtg&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDu5bOy8rlAhUiA2MBHS75DfYQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=separative%20interficere%20inter&f=false

Comment: On the same page you'll see this author points out "a double reference to interiority and **separation** similar to Lat. _inter_". And again the reference of Benveniste (1948) is given.

Comment: The so called "separation" explanation is a very old one and surely it wasn't proposed by Lopez Moreda or Filimonov or even Benveniste himself. As far as I can see (based on Walde and Hoffman or Szantyr), it goes back to Hermann Hirt *Indogermanische Grammatik* (volume IV, p. 59).

Comment: Here's the relevant passage from Hirt 1928: “Eine Zusammensetzung mit en ist wohl enter mit der Bedeutung ‘zwischen’, eig. ‘hineintretend’, erhalten in l. inter, osk. anter, air. ētar, ‘zwischen’, ahd. untar ‘zwischen’, ai. antár ‘innen, innerhalb, in, zwischen’. Wenn also idg. en-ter selbst schon ein zusammengesetztes Wort ist aus en+ter, s.o. 3, so sehen wir, daß schon in vorgeschichtlicher Zeit Präpositionen auf demsleben Weg enstanden sind, wie später l. versus, adversus u.a.” (p. 58) and "l. inter-ficere, ahd. untartuon, ai. antar dhījatē ‘verschwinden’" (p. 59)

Comment: Also it's worth perusing the relevant entry in WH (p. 443 in my edition). I wonder based on what evidence they made the claim that interficio "urspr. "*dazwischen tun", vgl. interfectus mit ai. antarhitah "verschwunden" ..." Let's examine it more thoroughly.

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks, Alex, for your comments and for quoting this relevant passage from Hirt (1928). You're absolutely right: it is also important to examine the parallelism with Sanskrit more thoroughly. I've just discovered another specific article on this topic in Spanish ("Sobre el significado etimológico de _interficere"_) but, unfortunately, it is not downloadable. ;-(  http://cosechador.siu.edu.ar/bdu3/Record/FILOUBA--oai:repositorio.filo.uba.ar:filodigital_9501

Answer (score 4):

interficere “to kill” goes with interfieri “to be destroyed” and interdicere “to ban”. Latin inter is cognate with (among others) Old High German untar, English under. This suggests that the descendants of IE *enter (or *H1enter) designate not only “in, between” but also “under, below”. In this case Latin interficere would have a similar semantic as the English “to take down”.

Comment: Interesting alternative to the explanation I found in the literature (cf.supra). I've just seen that Lewis & Short give yours at the very end of the lexical entry of _inter_: "Under, down, to the bottom; as _interire_, _interficere_". I wonder why this explanation is not given in the entries of these two verbs. Did they abandon it? http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=inter1&highlight=interficere%2Cinterire

Comment: Btw, I've been unable to find discussion of your interesting alternative proposal in the specialized literature. I'm not acquainted with Indo-European Linguistics and perhaps I don't look at the relevant sources. The ones I've consulted revolve around the "separative function" commented on in my post above (e.g., see the definition provided by the Indo-Europeanist Meier-Brügger (2003: page **187**):  "_interficere_: 'to separate (from life), to make disappear'. https://caio.ueberalles.net/Indo-European-Linguistics-Introduction/Indo-European_Linguistics%20-%20Michael%20Meier-Bru%CC%88gger.pdf